# Adding appointments to organizer's Outlook via iCalendar

Tags: php, outlook, phpmailer, icalendar, vcalendar

My situation: Appointments are stored in an external CMS. I want to send the appointments (via PHP/PHPMailer) to the end-user's mail client (Outlook). The user (organizer) should be able to send the appointments to himself and other attendees while he (the organizer) should get all replies from the attendees.

I'm able to send the appointment to all users (organizer and attendees), but if an attendent replies to the appointment, the organizer will get a notification, but it won't be visible to the organizers calendar entry. He even doesn't see the "Tracking" system to watch who accepted or denied the invitation.

It's hard to describe but hopefully, my problem is clarified.

Here's my setting:

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();                  
$mail->isHTML(false);
// Settings...
$mail->ContentType = 'text/calendar';
$mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-version',"1.0");
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-type',"text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8");
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding',"7bit");
$mail->addCustomHeader('X-Mailer',"Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0");
$mail->addCustomHeader("Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");

$mail->AddAddress('organizer@example.com');
$mail->AddAddress('attendent@example.com');

// Event data
$summary = 'Test event';
$location = 'Room 001';
$start = '20180310';
$start_time = '160000';
$end = '20180310';
$end_time = '163000';
$event_id = 123456;
$sequence = 0;
$status = 'CONFIRMED';

$mail->Subject = $summary";

$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .= "PRODID:-//Company//Anything//DE\r\n";
$ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= ORGANIZER;CN=\"Organizer\":MAILTO:organizer@example.com\r\n";
$ical .= "ATTENDEE;CN=\"Anybody\";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:attendent@example.com\r\n";
$ical .= "UID:" . strtoupper(md5($event_id)) . "-example.com\r\n";
$ical .= "SEQUENCE:" . $sequence . "\r\n";
$ical .= "STATUS:" . $status . "\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTAMPTZID=Europe/Berlin:" . date('Ymd') . 'T' . date('His') . "\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:" . $start . "T" . $start_time . "\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND:" . $end . "T" . $end_time . "\r\n";
$ical .= "LOCATION:" . $location . "\r\n";
$ical .= "SUMMARY:" . $summary . "\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:AnyText\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
$ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

// Send mail via PHPMailer...
```

Any suggestions how to place the event into the calendar of the organizer (from an external application), who is then able to receive replies from the attendees?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd recommend using [an ical builder class](https://github.com/iCalcreator/iCalcreator) rather than rolling your own manually like that.

PHPMailer has some [built-in iCal support](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_Ical) that makes it easy:

```
$ical = "your ical data in here, generated however you like";
$mail->Ical = $ical;
```

Be aware that iCal support in clients is extremely variable; it's hard to make iCal elements that work in gmail and Outlook at the same time.